# "Conoscere la verità" vs "sapere la verità"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Is there any difference of meaning between "conoscere la verità" and "sapere la verità"? AFAIK:

- conoscere: to know someone for the first time, to be acquainted/familiar with something, to be aware of something
- sapere: to know a fact, to get to know/to hear something, to be aware of something, to know how to do/to be able to do something

In this context, it seems to me that both the expressions mean the same: to be aware of the truth. If so, are they equally usual?

Comment: Interesting question. I put this as a comment since it is purely subjective, and I'll be glad to see if others agree or not. I feel that I'd use _conoscere la verità_ more in an almost philosophical sense (a sage, a priest, an initiate _conosce la verità_), while _sapere la verità_ sounds more mundane to me: someone is attempting to lie to me, but I _so la verità_, know the facts as they were.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all. It can take on a different nuance if the subject is in some way highlighted (with syntax or just your voice, paraverbal, etc.) regardless of the verb that is used in the sentence. In that case, the message is: one or more people know the truth while  others don't or could not. But it does not depend on the verb that you use. Example:

*Mario sì, lui conosce la verità!*

but it is the same of:

*Mario sì, lui sa la verità!*

Just to add other examples, the following sentences are both correct and have the same meaning:

1) *Mario sa la verità mentre Luisa non la conosce*;

2) *Mario conosce la verità mentre Luisa non la sa*